# Refresh a nested route with next.js app folder causes ReferenceError

Tags: next.js, next.js13, chakra-ui, referenceerror, app-folder

I have a project in which I am using **Next.js** with **ChakraUI**, I am facing an unexpected and unknown error, when I access any **nested route** and refresh the application dies and returns an error saying:

`Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Cannot access 'AuthModal' before initialization`

I have tried thousands of alternatives to fix this error but nothing works. I believe it is related to the next.js application folder, but I haven't tested it yet to say anything!

I followed all the recommendations of the libraries I'm using (Next.js and chakraUI)

##### The project architecture revolves around 3 main folders:

- **App folder:** next.js folder where all the routes are located;
- **Theme folder:** where all the stylizations and configurations of the UI chakra are located, following the chakra recommendations;
- **Components folder:** place where all components used in the application are made, including **layout component** (responsible for the root layout of the app);

I currently have 3 nested routes configured: **category, profile and store**

When I access the category and refresh, everything works as expected but if I do the same procedure on the other routes, the error unfortunately happens.

After a conversation with a dev friend, he told me that it could be **circular dependencies**, however, after debugging the code and running **Madge** (library that detects circular dependencies in the project), no circular dependencies were found.

**Note:** Auth Modal receives 3 child components: **login, signUp and forgotPass**. To render them correctly I need to pass a **type** props and make the following condition for them to be displayed according to the type passed:

```
function renderContent(type: AuthTypeEnum): React.ReactElement {
  switch (type) {
    case 'login':
      return <LoginForm />
    case 'register':
      return <RegisterForm />
    case 'forgot':
      return <ForgotPassForm />
    default:
      return <Text>Error</Text>
  }
}
```

When removing the function from the component, the app continues to work at least, but the error still occurs...

Reading the Next.js issues I found one that helped me remove the app crash, AuthModal was with **circular reference**. The child components were importing the textField component from the same components folder with the alias 'import TextField from "@/components", when I removed the alias, the error disappeared.